# Spring security, Error params got removed when using redirectStrategy

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security

I'm trying to create a `LoginFailureHandler` for handling failure in 2 cases. The first one is, when a user login via `/login` endpoint which should be redirected back to `/login?error={code}`. Second is when a user login via `/login/confirm?username={username}` (both pages send post request to /login) which should be redirected back to `/login/confirm?username={username}&error={code}`. My `LoginFailureHandler` looks like this

```
class LoginFailureHandler: SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
  override fun onAuthenticationFailure(request: HttpServletRequest,
                                       response: HttpServletResponse,
                                       exception: AuthenticationException) {
    val params = getParameters(request)
    if (params.containsKey(CustomParams.REQUIRE_CONFIRM)) {
      val url = buildConfirmationLoginURI(params.getFirst(CustomParams.USERNAME))
      redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, url) // to /login/confirm
      return
    }
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, buildLoginURI()) // to /login
  }

  private fun buildLoginURI(): String {
    return URIBuilder("/login")
      .setParameter("error", ErrorCode.INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD)
      .build()
      .toString()
  }

  private fun buildConfirmationLoginURI(username: String): String {
    return URIBuilder("/login/confirm")
      .setParameter(CustomParams.USERNAME, username)
      .setParameter("error", ErrorCode.INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD)
      .build()
      .toString()
  }
}
```

It can handle the second case just fine, but for the first case the parameter `error` got removed for some reason and got redirected back to `/login` instead of `/login?error={code}`.

Here's how I configure the security filter

```
http
  .authorizeRequests { requests -> ... }
  .csrf().disable() // for test
  .requestCache { cache -> cache.disable() }
  .formLogin { form ->
    form
      .loginPage("/login")
      .failureHandler(LoginFailureHandler())
      .permitAll()
   }
```

Edit:

Not sure if this is the right way to do it, but by adding this line of code it works just fine.

```
http
  .authorizeRequests { requests -> 
     requests.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
  }
```

but I already provided ::permitAll on the the formLogin section, isn't. why do I have to add the authorizeRequests twice to make it works, anybody knows?.